# UV meshes not showing ever since update to 2.80

Tags: mesh

I can't seem to get the default mesh to appear right in the new version of blender (2.8) this is with factory default settings. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's probably a problem with the last AMD driver, you can try an older one or go into the Render panel > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find the high quality normals in that panel, but a driver roll back helped. Inelegant perhaps, but effective.